# Xamarin app stay in landscape orientation when trying to put the Android phone upside down?

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-emulator, orientation, portrait

I just started a new Xamarin application.
When I change the orientation of the Android phone (emulator), everything respond as expected for landscape orientation (app resize properly) but when I put the phone in portrait upside down, the application stay in landscape orientation.

Is that possible to have the application works normally when the phone is upside down (portrait upside down)?

Answer (score 0):

> The application stay in landscape orientation when put the phone in portrait upside down.

It will be an expected result . It will work fine in real device because of gravity sensor .In emulator , gravity sensor is unavailable in default . So when put the phone in portrait upside down , the system determines that the  orientation  is still portrait up.

For more detail about  **sensors** you could check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion .